# Overlaying specific font pattern over column chart in ASP.NET Chart Control

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have been tasked with creating a stacked column chart. Each column can have multiple bars that are stacked (but with vertical gaps between each bar in each column). In other words, each column can have multiple data series. I need the ability to overlay each data series with a specific font pattern. Specifically, I need the ability to overlay an interdex hatch pattern over specific data series. I am not sure where to begin with this as the Chart helper does not appear to have any way to overlay a font pattern over a data series.

Comment: Have you looked into `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` ?

Comment: I read the documentation pretty thoroughly. I see that I can use a Graphics object but it's still a bit beyond me on how I could render the specific font on each series post paint.

Comment: You can easily change the font to each series independently, as long as the font is available in your machine. Not sure about your need to "render" the font. I'll post a sample chart.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that this is in MVC and, as a result, I don't have the ability to drag-and-drop chart controls. However, this is definitely very helpful.

Comment: Like i mentioned before, the Visual Studio designer is just a very helpful editing tool. The chart control can be created and configured from plain code the same way.

Comment: You're definitely correct and you've been invaluably helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, Sir ! Truly appreciate the positive feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample for `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting`. Note font size, type, color, etc are all configurable per series:

[image]

**EDIT**: Using customized labels, other than series values:

[image]

Comment: This looks good. Is the text itself editable? Right now, you have it set to show the value of the series; can this be changed to anything? I need to set it to a specific value due to the way that Interdex Hatch Patterns work. Also, is there any way you could post a sample of the code you used?

Comment: Yes, it can be changed to anything. I posted a new print screen. I did not need to write a single line of code to produce this chart...:O) It was all made by Visual Studio editor. But you could certainly accomplish the same thing using code-behind. In `WinForms` VS generates the equivalent code behind for the chart, but for ASP.NET it doesn't... Not sure if it is a configuration option or if that's just the way it is. But you can definitely do all that with code behind.